# operator return value issue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-value

I am having an issue with a return value with a += operator.

the following is the specific code that is related. If more code needs to be shown I will provide it:

```
    double operator+=(double b, const Account& c)
    {
      return b += c.getBalance();
    }
```

where it is implemented in the main:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i+1 << "- " << (balance += *AC[i]) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Total Balance: " << balance << std::endl;
```

output I am receiving:

```
1- 10302.98
2- 10302.98
3- 201.00
Total Balance: 0.00
```

output I am trying to get:

```
1- 10302.98
2- 20605.96
3- 20806.96
Total Balance: 20806.96
```

Comment: Don't use `*` characters to highlight code.  That makes the code more confusing.  Also, please post a [mcve]

Comment: Why are you returning `b += c.getBalance();`? Value of `b` will only change in `operator+=` function scope (as `b` is passed by value, not by reference). I think that what you really want to do is `return b + c.getBalance();` or perhaps pass `b` as reference `double operator+=(double& b, const Account& c);` and then increment it before returning `b += c.getBalance(); return b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in `b` by reference:

```
double operator+=(double &b, const Account& c)
{
  return b += c.getBalance();
}
```

instead of

```
double operator+=(double b, const Account& c)
{
  return b += c.getBalance();
}
```

Otherwise, think about what happens, the value of `balance`(0) is copied in with every call, rather than you actually summing to the memory location aliased by `balance`.

Comment: Please repost with a minimum example rather than all your code :) It's now harder to read what your asking than `*** highlight ***`. ;)

Comment: ok just reposted, I was told to provide a working version earlier, I am still trying to get used to the format that is supposed to used to be posted. Thanks for the answer again it is much appreciated!